# bash script - "docker run -it my_image bash" command not found

Tags: linux, bash, image, docker

we have a list of docker images, and we are trying to see what version of node/java/mongo.. is installed inside every image, using the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
version=""
file='images.txt'
while read line; do
        sudo docker pull $line 
        sudo docker run $line bash
        version=$(node -v)
        exit
        $version >> "version.txt"
        sudo docker image rm $line
done < $file
```

but we have an error on the "docker run" line which says "command not found"
the docker pull comannd works fine
we have also noticed that the while loop continues without waiting for the first docker pull to finish
and when we do the "docker run" command without the script it works fine and gets into the shell of the image.

we would appreciate any suggestions :)

Comment: try `version=$(sudo docker run $line node -v)`

Comment: Make sure to correctly quote `"$line"` and `"$file"` to avoid surprises if spaces or other characters sneak in.  The couple of lines after `docker run ... bash` don't look right, and I suspect you're trying to run commands in the subprocess in the outer shell script; that doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Zeitounator it worked when not in the script, the variable "version" doesnt hold the output command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you *probably* mean

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
        sudo docker pull "$line" 
        sudo docker run -it --rm "$line" node -v
done <images.txt >version.txt
```

... but code which doesn't do what you want to do is a terrible way to tell us what you actually want to do.  This will run `node -v` inside each container, where the `-it` option is crucial for getting output on standard output, and `--rm` takes care of what (I'm guessing) you were doing with a separate `rm`.  This still obviously depends on what exactly is in the input file.

Comment: you are right, what we try to do is taking line by line images that are stored in the images.txt file, pulling the image from registry and then runing a command inside with docker run , the output we wish to have is a file that hold :
image_name : node version/java version ...
i have tried doing what you wrote, it didnt get the output from the docker run command intothe version.txt file

Comment: If it prints the information to standard error, use `>version.txt 2>&1` at the end.